# C# логика действия переменных в форме

Tags: c#, winforms

вопрос по C#, как я могу осуществить передачу логику действия с форм Menu на форм1 или наоборот, я запутался.

У меня есть в форме Menu кнопка под названием (по билетам) у нее функция такова при нажатии рандомно выбирает 1 форма из 30 других, у каждой формы свой интерфейс и хочется чтоб после нажатия выбранная рандомная форма скрывала две кнопки потому что она не относится к рандому, а эти кнопки называются "предыдущий  билет" и "следующий билет" у них функция перехода на другую форму, и я вот что то попытался но не получается.

Код логики действия в самом форме1:

```
public void HideButtons()
{
    Button button4 = this.Controls.Find("knopkaNAZAD", true).FirstOrDefault() as Button;
    
    Button button5 = this.Controls.Find("knopkaVPERED", true).FirstOrDefault() as Button;
    
    if (button4 != null)
    {
        button4.Visible = false;
    }
    
    if (button5 != null)
    {
        button5.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Код кнопки под названием (по билетам) формы Menu:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();
    form1.HideButtons(); 
    form1.Show();
    
    // Проверяет, что список forms не пустой
    if (forms.Count > 0)
    {
        // Сгенерирует случайный индекс формы из списка
        int index = random.Next(0, forms.Count);
        
        // Получу выбранную форму по сгенерированному индексу
        Form selectedForm = forms[index];
        
        // Проверяет, что форма еще существует и активна
        if (selectedForm != null && !selectedForm.IsDisposed)
        {
            // Отобразит выбранную форму
            selectedForm.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            // Если форма уже удалена из памяти, удаляем ее из списка forms
            forms.RemoveAt(index);
            // Вызываем метод заново, чтобы показать другую форму
            button1_Click(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

А не нужно делать 30 форм, нужно сделать одну и на ней отображать билеты. Тогда будет легко переходить между билетами.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/883625)

Comment: Имеете ввиду все в одной форме запихать? 
Создать массивы и в нем все билеты с вопросами и ответами? И кнопки внизу рандом и из массива выбирается любая и выводится в одном большом label?

Comment: Примерно так. Выводить можно куда угодно: и в одну метку, и во множество, и в RichTextBox.

Comment: @чистов_n автор-то как раз понял ответ на свой вопрос, и ему не помешало то, что вы не поняли.